# Hint required on complex function problem

Tags: complex-analysis

If $\displaystyle f(z)=\left\{\begin{matrix}\frac{x^3y(y-ix)}{x^6+y^2},z\neq0
\\ 
0,z=0
\end{matrix}\right. $, prove that $\displaystyle \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}\rightarrow 0\:as\:z\rightarrow 0 $ along any radius vector but not as $z\rightarrow 0 $ along the curve $y=ax^3$.

I need some hints as how to approach/solve this problem.

Let $z=x+iy$. I put $y=x$ in z, I get $\displaystyle \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}=\frac{x^4(x-ix)}{(x^6+x^2)(x+ix)}$

This is not going anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $y=x$ you have $z=x+ix=x(1+i)$ and then as $z\rightarrow0$, $x\rightarrow0$ and so $$\displaystyle \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}=\frac{x^4(x-ix)}{(x^6+x^2)(x+ix)}=\frac{1-i}{1+i}\frac{x^4}{x^6+x^2}=-i\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}\rightarrow0$$ when $x\rightarrow0$.
Similar approach with the case $y=ax^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Separate it into real and imaginary parts as $$f(z) = \frac{x^3y^2}{x^6+y^2} - i \frac{x^4y}{x^6+y^2}.$$ Now consider $y=mx$ for $m \in \Bbb R$ and $x=0$, computing the limit as $x \to 0$ of $$\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}  = \frac{1}{x+iy} \left( \frac{x^3y^2}{x^6+y^2} - i \frac{x^4y}{x^6+y^2} \right).$$ Next take $y=ax^3$, simplify as possible and compute the limit.